# Store UserID in session?

Tags: session

To present user specific data, where do I store the userID of the user currently logged in? the Session?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the session would be an appropriate place for that information.  Assuming you are using the authentication features baked into the ASP.NET framework, you will either be loading the user ID from HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name or looking it up from that value.

Answer (score 2):

yes. sesssion is used for storing user specific data.